# Stop rows with name label names merging in Excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have 2 rows in my pivot table, with the same label "Josh Kennedy". When the pivot table is created, it combines them and makes all the stats distorted, as it combines their stats. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Not without you providing more detail about your data set. Pivot tables are all about aggregating data for specific labels. If one of your labels is "Josh Kennedy" and your "stats"  sum or average by that label, then that's what the pivot table will do. I suggest you EDIT YOUR QUESTION and mock up a data sample and the desired result in the pivot table. Then POST A COMMENT to alert the followers of this question and we can show you what is required to get to that result.

Comment: Are these distinct individuals? If so , in addition to teylyn's comments you are going to have to think about how you create a unique identifier for the source data rows that splits them that can then be used in the pivot.

Answer (score 0):

That's what PivotTables do: They aggregate things. If the issue is that you have two people called Josh Kennedy, then you'll need to bring in another field into the PivotTable that will separate the data, such as a unique CustomerID field, or an address field, or similar.